# Why does evently suggest $$(this) to save state?

Tags: jquery, couchdb, couchapp, evently

As explained [here](http://couchapp.org/page/evently-do-it-yourself-ii-state), to save state which must be accessible in different events, `$$(this)` is recommended, like this:

```
$$(this).filters = "myvalue";
```

What does that syntax mean? Why `$$` (double dollar)? Why `this`? Why the `()` (parentheses)?

That code is not working for me anyway. I must use something like:

```
$.filters = "myvalue";
```

I would like to understand why the second form is working, and the first one not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the source code of eventlly, `$$` is just a shorthand for jQuery's `data` method:

```
function $$(node) {
  var data = $(node).data("$$");
  if (data) {
    return data;
  } else {
    data = {};
    $(node).data("$$", data);
    return data;
  }
};
```

so, in a nutshell - it calls `data` on whatever jQuery returns for your argument, if there is no data attached it creates empty object, use this as new `data` and returns it.

```
$.filters = "myvalue"
```

This works by assigning the value to global jQuery object, while `$$` attaches your data to object represented by query.